# С++ - Способы вернуться на начало файла, кроме input.seekg()

Tags: c++

Какие есть способы вернуться на начало файла, кроме `input.seekg(0, input.beg)`?

Answer (score 1):

1) Вариация к Вашему коду (предпочитаю `ios::`):

```
fstream stream_fin; 
... 
stream_fin.seekg(0L, std::ios_base::beg); // у Вас указано input.beg(), можно так
```

2) Осуществлять побайтовый сдвиг назад до начала файла;

3) Закрыть и открыть файл заново;

Примечание: перед `seekg()` надо вроде сбросить состояние потока `stream_fin.clear()`, проверьте этот момент.